# WordPress video slider with text

Tags: video, wordpress, vimeo

I am building a video portfolio website for a friend and we are keen to have a video slider similar (i.e. the same) to what can be found on www.thiscityspeaks.com

the slider needs to have the following features:
  - responsive
  - display text with links to the right of the video
  - display videos from Vimeo
  - series of videos below that you can scroll through

Basically it just needs to be as can be seen on the website linked above.

I had a look at the source for the page and found that it was developed on the VideoZoom template by WPZoom. I have purchased the theme in the hope that with a bit of work I'd be able to transfer the video slider functionality into the theme that I'm using for my site, but unfortunately the slider functionality is so deeply embedded into the theme it is going to be a very major task doing that.

I was therefore wondering if anyone could make any suggestions on a WordPress plugin, or anything else that might work, to get a slider with the functionality that I'm looking for.

In advance, thanks very much for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that site you linked to is just using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). Flexslider is free to use and can be made to work with just about any video source, be it YouTube, Vimeo, or something else.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for your response :-) Yeah, I noticed it's based on Flexslider. Just not really across how to get all the features I want, especially the text panel on right, to work.

Comment: After adding the flexslider html code to your page, you can add in the appropriate html code to display whatever you like. If you're using Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress, these things can be changed quickly and painlessly from the Admin interface.